# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, babeljs

I am using babel to bundle the file and run the bundled file to run the server. However, I am getting an error of 'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module' on heroku. I am using `@babel/cli`, `@babel/core`, `@babel/node`, `@babel/preset-env` and `babel-plugin-module-resolver`. My babelrc looks like following

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "graphql-tag"
  ]
}
```

Here is my script on package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "env-cmd -f ./dev/.env nodemon --exec babel-node app/server.js",
    "syncGraphql": "rsync -a --prune-empty-dirs --include 'app/graphql/*' --include '*.graphql' 'app/graphql' 'dist'",
    "build": "babel app/ -d dist && npm run syncGraphql",
    "staging": "env-cmd -f ./staging/.env nodemon --exec babel-node app/server.js",
    "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon --exec babel-node app/server.js",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/server.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
```

I found similar question with two solution. One with the same babelrc I have and another to use `type: module` in package.json. But this way I get other issue like

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module (.....)
```

There is no problem while I run the script `yarn start:dev`. But, I get the issue when running a bundled file on heroku

[image]

Here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "api-server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Description",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist",
    "dev": "env-cmd -f ./dev/.env nodemon --exec babel-node app/server.js",
    "syncGraphql": "rsync -a --prune-empty-dirs --include 'app/graphql/*' --include '*.graphql' 'app/graphql' 'dist'",
    "build": "babel app/ -d dist && npm run syncGraphql",
    "staging": "env-cmd -f ./staging/.env nodemon --exec babel-node app/server.js",
    "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon --exec babel-node app/server.js",
    "start": "node dist/server.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-errors": "^1.9.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.24.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "better-module-alias": "^1.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dataloader": "^2.0.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "github-graphql-client": "^1.0.0",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^7.0.5",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "http-status": "^1.5.0",
    "isomorphic-git": "^1.8.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "merge-graphql-schemas": "^1.7.8",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.10",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-github2": "^0.1.12",
    "passport-gitlab2": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/node": "^7.14.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-graphql-tag": "^3.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.2",
    "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `.mjs` instead of `.js`.

Comment: but .js is working while I run yarn dev.

Comment: Heroku executes `npm start` not `npm start:dev`. Thus you should ensure first that locally `npm start` works. Share your entire `package.json`. It gives information about your dependencies and dev dependencies. Heroku does not install dev dependencies. Furthermore share your entire build.log

Comment: @TinNguyen I have shared my package.json and there is no issue while building(git push heroku master). I have attached screenshot of an error though.